# How can I dynamically create a modal with a specific class in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Hi I have been stuck with a problem for days now, and so far no research has proved sufficient. I am trying to create a simple modal in Ionic 2 with a specific class (or id).

I need something as simple as this:

```
<ion-modal class="myDifficultToAddClass">
...
</ion-modal>
```

This is my code:

```
import { NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component(...)
class PageBehindTheModal {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }
  presentProfileModal() {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { randomData: randomData });
    profileModal.present();
  }
}

@Component(...)
class Profile {
  constructor(params: NavParams) {
    console.log('Some info: ', params.get('randomData'));
  }
}
```

I have tried to encapsulate the view with ViewEncapsulation from angular/core in order to use a local css, but this css will be available globally (and I cannot "style" only this particular modal - so this is not a solution):

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
```

I was hoping to find a simple solution like:

```
// create(component, data, opts)
create(Profile, { randomData: randomData }, { cssClass: 'myDifficultToAddClass' })
```

Unfortunately, my wish didn't come true :).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a selector to your component

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    selector:'somemodal',
})
```

And now you can set all your css on the element somemodal

```
somemodal {
    // dostuff
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! Such a simple solution, but so hard to find... Thank you sir! Problem gone!

As a tip for anybody who might encounter this problem in the future: 
**You may need to use !important keyword on the element's CSS attributes** (most of them are overwritten by other Ionic components's CSS)

Answer (score 5):

You can now pass a CSS class name as an optional parameter when creating the modal.

```
  presentProfileModal() {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { 
      randomData: randomData }, {
      cssClass: 'myDifficultToAddClass'
    });
    profileModal.present();
  }
```

Find the official documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/#advanced)

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Thanks on behalf of those who are too lazy to go through the documentation. :/