# How to disable toolbar-background for some ion-navbars?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

My app is in cordova, ionic 3.2. I want global style for ion-navbar component. So I declared style with .toolbar-background in variables.scss file. Now the style of ion-navbar in all pages are changed. its working fine. Now I want to disable the style for a specific ion-navbar only. Can anybody help me on how it possible please?

eg: 
I have below code in variable.scss;

```
.toolbar-background{ 
  background-color: red !important; 
}
```

I have below code for header in app.html page(for left side menu header);
The background of this toolbar is red.

```
 <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title text-center>
       Hellow!
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

Below is the code for footer in the app.html; 
The background of this toolbar is red. **I do not want red color only for this component. How to disable this style that showing due to toolbar-background?**

```
<ion-footer> 
    <ion-navbar secondary > 
this is the footer
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-footer>
```

Comment: Please add your code and/or a jsfiddle. Its really hard to understand anything just from reading.

Comment: Every component has a selector property which adds an element before the html so you can that to your css like app .toolbar-background { ... }

Comment: Hi @misha130, thanks for the reply Unfortunately I didn't understand what it means. Could you please give an example with my code please

Comment: Hi @Baruch could you please give ur suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40977407/2490286